# Trasparent text in html

Tags: html, css

I have this:
[image]
But i want this:
[image]
Code is here:

```css
    body {margin: 0;}
      img {
        width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
      }
      div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
          height: 100px;
          left: 100px;
          top: 100px;
          background-color: #ff08;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 60px;
          line-height: 100px;
          font-family: arial;
          border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/27/08/39/mountain-7619151_960_720.jpg">
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background-color: #ff08; left: 100px; top: 100px; text-align: center;">TEXT</div>
```

How to do it?
i can't use bacground-image instead img.

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity`, with a rather low value:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #ff08;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: arial;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/11/27/08/39/mountain-7619151_960_720.jpg">
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background-color: #ff08; left: 100px; top: 100px; text-align: center;">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this lower the opacity on the whole element rather than the text only?

Comment: the color of the text is still black

Comment: @Coolis on the whole element